# I am trying to create drop down menu in django but my code is showing only text box ? Help Appricated

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have defined modles.py, view.py, and forms.py but unable to get the drop-down menu. at initial, I have created moodle.py using os_choice and later on a substitute in the operating_system. further, I have created forms and I am using crispy forms to render in front page. likewise, I have defined this in views.py but when I see it on the font page it shows only a text file, not a drop-down with choices.

**Here is my model.py code:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

# Create your models here.




class ResultQuery(models.Model):
    os_choice = (
        ('Windows 10', 'Windows 10'),
        ('Windows 8', 'Windows 8'),
        ('Linux', 'Linux'),
    )
    operating_system = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, choices=os_choice)

    level = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    program = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    exam_year = models.IntegerField()
    institute = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    symbol_num = models.IntegerField()
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dob = models.DateField()
    sgpa = models.TextField()
    result = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    subject1_code=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject1_title=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject1_credit_hour=models.TextField()
    subject1_grade_point=models.TextField()
    subject1_grade=models.TextField()
    subject1_remarks=models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    subject2_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject2_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject2_credit_hour = models.TextField()
    subject2_grade_point = models.TextField()
    subject2_grade = models.TextField()
    subject2_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    subject3_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject3_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject3_credit_hour = models.TextField()
    subject3_grade_point = models.TextField()
    subject3_grade = models.TextField()
    subject3_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    subject4_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject4_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject4_credit_hour = models.TextField()
    subject4_grade_point = models.TextField()
    subject4_grade = models.TextField()
    subject4_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    subject5_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject5_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject5_credit_hour = models.TextField()
    subject5_grade_point = models.TextField()
    subject5_grade = models.TextField()
    subject5_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    subject6_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject6_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject6_credit_hour = models.TextField()
    subject6_grade_point = models.TextField()
    subject6_grade = models.TextField()
    subject6_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return smart_text(self.name)
```

**Here is my forms.py**

```
    from django import forms
    from search.models import ResultQuery
    from django.forms import MultipleChoiceField, ChoiceField, Form
    
    
    class ResultForm(forms.Form):
          Reg_No=forms.CharField(label="Registration Number")
          Name=forms.CharField(label="Your Name")
          OS=forms.CharField(label="Operating System")
```

**And here is my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ResultForm
from .models import ResultQuery



def home(request):
    form=ResultForm(request.POST or None)
    template_name = "home.html"
    context = {"form": form}
    if form.is_valid():
        objects = ResultQuery.objects.filter(reg_no=form.cleaned_data['Reg_No'], name=form.cleaned_data['Name'], operating_system=form.cleaned_data['OS'])
        context['objects'] = objects

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing it like so?

```py
    from django import forms
    from search.models import ResultQuery
    from django.forms import MultipleChoiceField, ChoiceField, Form
    
    
    class ResultForm(forms.Form):
          Reg_No=forms.CharField(label="Registration Number")
          Name=forms.CharField(label="Your Name")
          OS=forms.ChoiceField(choices=ResultQuery.os_choice)
```